# How to delete the data of a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers

```
char *p = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

... let p point to some chars

free(p);
char *p = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
```

Since freeing p doesn't delete the data stored at the particular memory address I'm facing the problem that for large pointers the newly allocated memory overlaps with the old one what is obviously problematic. How can I delete the data to which a pointer points to ?

Comment: Put new data there.

Comment: "*is obviously problematic*" Why?

Comment: @EricPostpischil but if there is old data and I put in a new char at the first position and then iterate until '\0', this will give me not the desired result, since the old data interferes with the new...

Comment: Put a new `'\0'` there.

Comment: "*then iterate until `'\0'`*" The memory returned by `malloc` is not initialized to any particular values, and this holds true regardless of whether it's the 1st `malloc` or the Nth `malloc`, regardless of whether it comes right after a `free` or not. If you rely on a `'\0'` character being there, better make sure *you* wrote it there in the first place

Comment: This question should not have been closed. The comment is "needs details or clarity" but there is no information about what details are required. The question is easily answerable; OP is just confused about how `malloc` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assume that memory returned from `malloc` is initialized to anything. It may be initialized to zero the first time, but you can't rely on that behavior.

You can call `memset` to clear the memory returned from `malloc`. Or consider using `calloc`, which zeros out the memory before returning the pointer to you.

In general programs only use `memset` or `calloc` if they really need the memory buffer to be initialized to zero. If you're just going to copy a string into it, you don't need to initialize it to zero first; you can just copy the string and (if necessary) append a `'\0'` to the end.

Comment: `calloc()` is a real champ in that it makes your calculations more obvious and clears the memory, too.

Comment: Glib answers before a question has been clarified risk overlooking the real problem. Signs are OP is not initializing the memory they allocate, meaning their use of their first `malloc` is “succeeding” only because it is early in their program and they get zero-allocated space. In other circumstances, it may fail.

Comment: I don't understand why you're accusing me of posting a "glib" answer when your own answer, posted before mine, was "put new data there." Regardless, no clarification is necessary here, it's obvious why OP is observing this behavior.

Comment: I did not post an answer.

Comment: I think you're relying on a technicality here. What was your intent in making that statement, if not to answer the OP's question?

Comment: First, Stack Overflow questions and answers are not intended to be a dialog. Stack Overflow is intended to create a durable repository of questions and answers useful to other people in the future. When a question is ill-posed, I may not want to enter an answer that will not serve that goal of Stack Overflow. Nonetheless, a comment may aide the OP and/or prompt them to think in a certain direction and/or prompt a response that may clarify the question. Comments are ephemeral and should not be taken as answers.

Comment: Fine, you posted a glib comment then.

Comment: Yes, which is fine for a comment. The issue is not glibness *per se*; the issue is, as I noted in my comment, that answering before a question has been clarified risks overlooking the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such concept as "deleting" data in C. When you allocate some memory for data, there will always be data there. It will probably start as garbage until you put your data there, and your data will stay there until you put something else there. You could replace your data with something like 0s or 0xFFs with memset(), which would overwrite your data. You must do so /before/ free()ing it.

Answer (score -1):

```
void myfree(void *ptr, size_t size)
{
    volatile char *ucptr = ptr;
    if(ucptr) while(size--) *ucptr++ = 0;
    asm("");
    free(ptr);
}
```

```
char *p = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(*p));

//... let p point to some chars

myfree(p, 10 * sizeof(*p));
char *p = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: @tadman ️. But it does not set memory before free as requested by OP

Comment: Ah, I see. True. Though that might be considered extraneous and could get optimized out by your compiler.

Comment: This code does not set memory before `free` either. That is because a `memset` of the memory immediately before a `free` has no observable effect as defined by the C standard and therefore [may be optimized away](https://godbolt.org/z/enb6hd). And it certainly would not guarantee anything about the subsequently allocated memory.

Comment: @EricPostpischil indeed